# How to fully set background color to drawer top side?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have custom drawer in my app where drawer top part doesn't have setted color:

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

**Code:**

```
class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 250,
      child: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            new ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.3),
                  child: DrawerHeader(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Image(
                          width: 130.0,
                          image: AssetImage('lib/assets/user_happy.png'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Andres Hunter',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.green),
                  title: Text('Favorites'),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.info, color: Colors.green),
                  title: Text('About'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutScreen()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Divider(
                    height: 2.0,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.apps, color: Colors.green),
                    title: Text('Version: 1.6'),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your drawer with a `SafeArea` widget?

Comment: No, which widget do you mean?

Comment: Wrap the `Drawer` with `SafeArea`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I can see the issue.

Can you see your `Appar` which is going to be on top of the emulator? The widget fits perfectly and if you implement the `drawer` widget at the same level inside your `Scaffold`, it will work perfectly fine.

Check the drawer example here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer